# Typescript Pick type not mapping intellisense

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

The Typescript [Pick type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) is not mapping intellisense in vscode (or stackblitz). If `MyType` has a documented property, then you define a type as `Pick<MyType, 'someProperty'>`, then you mouseover `.someProperty` you won't see the documentation or if you right-click -> Go to Definition it won't find any. It will for `Partial<MyType>` though.

I made workaround type `PickPartial<T, K extends keyof T>` and demonstration [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pick-partial?file=index.ts). Is this a Typescript or vscode bug or how `Pick` should behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to call this a TypeScript bug.  See this [modified demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pick-partial-vhjiak?file=index.ts).  In order for the documentation to come through, the constraint of the mapped type has to be just a `keyof`; this was implemented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15821).  However, modifiers such as `readonly` come through if the constraint is a type parameter whose constraint is a `keyof`, as it is in `Pick`.  Documentation should be changed to come through in the same circumstances that modifiers do.

Comment: I don't see a TypeScript bug already filed.  Do you want to file one or shall I?

Comment: I'm going to file the bug.  And I have a draft fix that's only a few lines of diff!

Comment: Thank you, knew it didn't seem right but wasn't confident.